# ING trouble in sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, gerunds, verb-forms

My sentence is:

> My goals focus mainly on **developING** my **designING** skills, in particular jewellery and clothes design, as well as **gainING** experience and **masterING** the art of **drawING** and fashion **designING** ability. In addition, it would be beneficial for me to improve my English fluency.

It seems very odd to me to use one 'ing' form after another 'ing' form, but I cannot imagine another construction for this sentence. Even if commas are used, I can't remove the 'INGs'. Could someone help me with making it sound more correct?

Answer (score 1):

One can also say "design skills" if that sounds better to your ear.

I would advise you to break the long sentence up into several sentences, because you're getting lost in a tangle of verbs.

What you cannot say is "*mastering*...fashion designing *ability*".

We cannot 'master an ability'. We can *develop* an ability and master an art or skill.

*I would also like to master the art of drawing.*

Answer (score 1):

You can break the first sentence into two sentences; your second sentence is fine as written.

> My goals focus mainly on developjng my design skills, particularly in
>   jewellery and fashion.

"Design, skills" is the usual way of saying "designing skills".

"Fashion" is  a nice substitute for "clothes design".

> As well, I hope to master the art of drawing and gain experience.

If you use "fashion" in the first sentence, no need to repeat it in the second sentence.

Mentioning "abilities" just gets in the way.

Your original topic title mentioned infinitives which is the style that I am suggesting for getting around the "mastering ... drawing" contruction which seems to bother you, but which is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: You are suggesting a rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

These are gerunds, not infinitives. Infinitives are "to have", "to swim", "to desire", et cetera. But this sentence sounds completely natural already - there's no need to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two places in your sentence where ING is not needed or appropriate.

- 1) ...designing skills 
  should be **design skills**
- 2) "..fashion designing ability.."
  should be simply "...**fashion design**
  (but if you feel you need to include "ability", you would say you aim to   "develop" or "improve" that ability, not " master" it.

Oh, and if you do leave out "ability" (as I suggested): change "art" to "arts", since it refers to two distinct arts, *drawing* and *fashion design*

(Any further comments, about your style, or about how this text makes you seem, would be "opinion-based". You asked only about the INGs.)